# dcat metadata on Ckan

Tags: java, metadata, ckan, opendata

I am new to the whole open data culture, so pardon my ignorance.
I was asked to create a java program that will post files to a ckan installation. This is done and I can add some of the basic metadata information that ckan uses by default.
Now i have to extend this to use c-cat metadata, but i have no idea how to do it! for example i use this for the ckan information

```
HttpEntity reqEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
                     .addPart("file", cbFile)
                     .addPart("url",new StringBody(HOST+"/files/"+date+"/"+uploadFileName,ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN))
                     .addPart("upload",cbFile)
                     .addPart("author",new StringBody(AUTHOR,ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN))
                     .build();
```

How can i embed d-cat information that is in the form of

```
:ds1 a dcat:Dataset ;
     dcat:distribution :dist1 .  
:dist1 a dcat:Distribution ;
     dcat:downloadURL <http://example.org/dist1.csv>;
     dcat:format [ rdfs:label "CSV" ].
```

as taken from the w3 website.
This post was also posted on [google's CKAN group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/ckan-global-user-group/W3KnmbUyJB0)

Answer (score 0):

CKAN will publish the DCAT metadata for you if you install the ckanext-dcat module. See: https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-dcat